# How to refresh "=NOW()" in a cell via a activex button?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to have a button that refreshes time (A Cell with the current time) in MS Excel but I can't find any article about it. Can someone here point me in the right direction?

I expect to have a button that which when pressed will refresh the time(=TODAY()) in a cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub btnCommand_Click()
    Sheet1.Range("A1").Formula = "=NOW()"
End Sub
```

... or ...

```
Private Sub btnCommand_Click()
    Sheet1.Range("A1") = Now()
End Sub
```

If your worksheet CodeName is equal to **Sheet1**, **A1** is the cell you want to update and the technical name of your button is **btnCommand**.

You may also want to format your cell as **Time**.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This works. I also tried to use Cells(10, "F").Calculate.